# ModX Revolution FormIt pass url variable to form

Tags: variables, modx, formit

I am using FormIt extra in Modx Revolution and I have an url like

```
.../page.html?data1=value1&data2=value2
```

I want to pass these values into new form on the page. How do I do that without using JS? THX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved using [[!FormItRetriever]] snippet..

```
    [[!FormIt?
   &hooks=`redirect`
   &store=`1`
   &clearFieldsOnSuccess=`1`]]
```

Set input value: value="[[+fi.someValue]]"

On Landing page paste: [[!FormItRetriever]] before FormIt call..
and use same input value="[[+fi.someValue]]" in form.